# Why is OpenCV with sublime text 3 and python 3.8 quitting unexpectedly?

Tags: opencv, sublimetext3, video-capture, python-3.8

I am trying to use OpenCV to video capture my webcam. Each time I run the program, python quits unexpectedly, and the code says [Finishd in 0.3s with exit code -6]
Operating System - Catalina 10.15.3
Using sublime text 3
Python 3.8

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: If you copied your code here correctly, change ```cam``` with ```cap```

Comment: Whoops, the code was incorrectly copied. The issue is still persisting with cap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Sublime's [build systems](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html) can't handle GUI window creation like `cv2.imshow()`. I believe it has to do with how the build system is executed using the `subprocess` module. You'd run into the same problem if you were trying to display an image using `Pillow` or `matplotlib`, for example. Please note that you can do image *processing* just fine within Sublime, as long as you don't try to display the results.

The easiest way around it is to just keep a Terminal window open and manually run your scripts from the command line after saving.

Comment: Got it. I will do that moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably help to add some error handling to your code. For instance, after

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Try to put something like this:

```
if !cap.isOpened():
    print("Error")
    exit(1)
```

Then, after

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

try:

```
if !ret:
    print("Error: frame not captured")
```

At least this should give you some hints as to where the problem is.

Good luck

Andreas

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply